# SQL Server -- Is it possible to step through a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure being executed from an ASP.NET application.  Is it possible to attach to the procedure and step through it using SQL Server 2005?

Note, in this instance, I am not using a DataAdapter.  I'm going in blind.  The connection string is being created on the fly, so I don't have access to the schema from the Visual Studio 2005 designer.

I was hoping for a solution similar, for example, to how you attach to a process on a remote server and when a break point is hit, the debugger fires.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can debug a stored procedure directly from your ASP.NET application (i.e. set a break point in your .NET code and the step into a stored procedure), but it is possible to debug it directly using visual studio.

Here is a [great article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/debugging-stored-procedures-in-visual-studio-2005) on SQLTeam.com describing how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at

- [Debugging SQL Server 2005 Stored
  Procedures](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102846/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051607-1.aspx)
- [How to debug stored procedure in SQL
  server 2005](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/435c0c43-571a-442d-9fb9-f3f495b1f2ed)
- [Debugging a SQL Stored Procedure](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/050106.htm)
- [Debugging Stored Procedures in SQL
  Server 2005](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article27.aspx)
- [Debugging Stored Procedures in
  Visual Studio 2005](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/debugging-stored-procedures-in-visual-studio-2005)
- [SQL Server 2005 Management Studio
  Part 2](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3640896/SQL-Server-2005-Management-Studio-Part-2.htm)
- [Debugging stored procedures on SQL
  Server 2005](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/joeycalisay/archive/2007/09/26/debugging-stored-procedures-on-sql-server-2005.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

absolutely

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article27.aspx is a link.

edit
sorry realised the initial link was subscription only, this link is better

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SQL Profiler to find out what is going on "behind the scenes".